# Tensorflow Object Detection: Not Predicting using Custom Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am using this repository has the basecode (https://github.com/ndaidong/tf-object-detection) which uses Tensorflow Object Detection, to detect the review, date, likes and rating in a screenshot of a review.

I went through 100 images (just wanted to test if this was possible), annotating the images with 4 labels (review, date, likes and rating), converted from XML to CSV and then generated the TFrecords. This was done for both training and evaluation data. 100 images for training and 20 images for evaluation. Here is a screenshot of what I have annotated.
[Click here for an example of the annotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdrPf.png)

For the training, I used the following config

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 4
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
      height: 500
      width: 2000
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.99999989895e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.0299999993294
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.999700009823
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000475
          train: true
        }
      }
      use_depthwise: true
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.99999989895e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.0299999993294
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.999700009823
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000475
            train: true
          }
        }
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011921
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.20000000298
        max_scale: 0.949999988079
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.333299994469
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.300000011921
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.990000009537
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 35
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00400000018999
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.949999988079
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
      decay: 0.899999976158
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  num_steps: 200
}
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "temp/data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "configs/reviews/labels.pbtxt"
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 20
  max_evals: 10
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "temp/data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "configs/reviews/labels.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

As you can see I am trying to train data from scratch and not using existing models. The reason for this is because I am not trying to find general objects that has already training.

I adjusted the fixed_shape_resizer as the image dimensions of the reviews were roughly around 2000 in width and 500 in height.

I only used 200 steps for the training (Do I need to do more?), as I noticed in Tensorboard after a few 100 steps it was starting to learn, as the 'Loss' result started to go down quite a bit. [Click here to see Tensorboard results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAzFC.png)

However, when I export/freeze the graph and then try to predict. Nothing gets predicted. It all looks okay to me. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just 200 images should be good enough for doing object detection, atleast for testing. You are probably doing some step incorrectly, refer  https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many steps involved in using this API so not sure which one you might have mistaken however what I feel is that if you are training object detection model from scratch then you need huge dataset. 100 images is very tiny dataset. You can look into the size of dataset on which pretrained object detection models are trained like ResNet, ImageNet. There dataset is insanely huge. So to get results you need to use either pretrained model or larger dataset. In order to increase dataset you can do image augmentation of existing images outside this API and adjust their annotations using algorithms. When I was doing similar exercise I used around 10K images with pretrained model and image augmentation.

If you are using labelImg for image annotation make sure you are aware of [this](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/issues/159) issue in the tool

Comment: To get results, how many images do you suggest I should annotate/train on? I will do what you suggest and use existing an existing model to train from. Is it possible to get the machine to detect 'likes' and 'rating' from an image/screenshot of a review?

Comment: With pretrained model you can start with 100 as well just to check. Additionally what you can do is increase dataset gradually of varying contexts to see if results are improved or not. There is no specific number I can suggest because it depends on many factors but try with 1K-2K images. But pretrained models will definitely detect. Can you also post the snapshot of model fitting logs.
In my case I removed random crop augmentation from configuration pipeline and that did helped.

Comment: I have removed 'ssd_random_crop' and added fine_tune_checkpoint to use model 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29'.  See screenshot https://imgur.com/9rVOBTS. It's now repeating twice. Also its saying there are quite a few variables missing. See screenshot - https://imgur.com/yK5Qr1U